# Can tapeworms from brine shrimp cause infection to humans or to fish?

Tags: aquarium, fish, parasites, infections, brineshrimp

I have angelfish which laid eggs which turned into fry. I am feeding them with baby brine shrimp.

We all know that brine shrimps (especially the ones which look orange and often used for fish feed) are infected with tapeworms.¹
Now I am worried, **can tapeworms can cause tapeworm infection to the pet keepers?**

¹[Parasites give brine shrimp superpowers - Science News for Students](https://www.sciencenewsforstudents.org/article/parasites-give-brine-shrimp-super-powers#:%7E:text=The%20tissue%20of%20brine%20shrimp,arsenic%2C%20a%20new%20study%20finds)

Comment: the brineshrimp or eggs you buy is hatched  in clean saltwater so it will be free from parasites like tapeworm,only wild brineshrimp will be carriers of tapeworm.to be sure no parasites are present you can hatch your own brineshrimp.

Comment: @trondhansen: Thanks a lot. That's why I highlighted the word `orange`. When I hatch or most(all I've seen) of hobbyist show their hatchery on youtube the brine shrimp color will be orange which according to some research is because of tapeworm. Now, does that mean these orange looking brineshrimp are infected by tapeworm?

Comment: The color of brineshrimp depends on the food you give,feed spirulina and you get green brineshrimp,feed yeast and you get grey/pink brineshrimp.low oxygen will cause red brineshrimp due to the production of hemoglobin in  brineshrimp.i have never seen tapeworm infected brineshrimp but i know tapeworm are white.